# Change date mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy after get file excel with EPPLUS - MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, http, epplus

I have a `input text` date time with format : dd/mm/yyyy ,

and `Action` ExportExcel :

```
public ActionResult ExportExcel(Datetime date)
{
    var stream = CreateExcelFile();

    var buffer = stream as MemoryStream;

    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=ExcelDemo.xlsx");

    Response.BinaryWrite(buffer.ToArray());

    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Before i submit form to this `action`, i format `input text`  : mm/dd/yyyy .

When i get file excel, i want to reformat `input text` : dd/mm/yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

You should use DateTime format.For example if you want this format:"18/8/2016" do something  like this in your ActionResult:

```
string format = "d/M/yy";
var exceltime = time.ToString(format);
```

More information you can find here:
[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: But input parameter "date" can not get values : DD/MM/YYYY. It get value : null , when i submit :DD/MM/YYYY.

Answer (score 0):

So you know your date is always going to be dd/MM/yyyy

What you can do is change your input type to string and then transform it into datetime.

```
public ActionResult ExportExcel(string date)
{
    DateTime original_date = DateTime.Now;
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(date))
    {
        originial_date = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
    .
    .
}
```